# Реализация взаимодействия между ASP.Net MVC и Python

Tags: python, c#, json, rest

Всем привет! Возникла необходимость связать два приложения: ASP.Net MVC и приложение на Python, каждое работает со своей бд. Суть: с приложения ASP отдаем запрос - получаем Json, сформированный из данных приложения python. Полный ноль в этом деле, не представляю как подступиться и с чего начать, какими библиотеками и как реализовать взаимодействие, возможно есть какие-нибудь примеры. (фактически реализация REST Api на уровне базовых запросов)

Comment: Я ничего не понял. asp.net mvc - это, я так понял, ваш вебсайт (или апи), python - это не приложение, это язык программирования. Что именно у вас на питоне написано вы не уточнили, а значит говорить не о чем по сути.

Comment: Уточняю: asp.net mvc - вебсайт, приложение на python - простой сокетный сервер, по мере необходимости к нему можно подключиться и выполнить операции обработки данных, которые записываются в бд. Требуется, чтобы данное python приложение могло обрабатывать http запросы от asp.net вебсайта и отправлять определенные данные из своей бд в формате json в ответ на запрос вебсайта.

Comment: при такой постановке задачи абсолютно не имеет значения, есть у вас asp.net вебсайт или нет. Развивайте ваше приложение на python, добавляйте ему http и json возможности, в чем проблема с этим?